# How to apply one NOT aggregating function on a time window

Tags: scala, window-functions

I would like to use a window function but I don't want to do an agregate function, is it possible?

here is my issue.

I have a list of comment on movies and I would like to know, for each comment, in the past 10 minutes, what is the comment with the smallest distance from him.

ex:

Here is my table of comment:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

var commentaires = sc.parallelize(Array((1, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:19:50"), "super film"), (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:19:58"), "très bon film"),(3, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:21:50"), "tres mauvais"), (4, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:21:51"), "incroyable ce film"), (5, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:21:58"), "incroyable ce film"))).toDF("num", "CommentDate", "comment")
```

I get the table:

```
+---+-------------------+------------------+
|num|CommentDate        |comment           |
+---+-------------------+------------------+
|1  |2017-03-12 03:19:50|super film        |
|2  |2017-03-12 03:19:58|très bon film     |
|3  |2017-03-12 03:21:50|tres mauvais      |
|4  |2017-03-12 03:21:51|incroyable ce film|
|5  |2017-03-12 03:21:58|incroyable ce film|
+---+-------------------+------------------+
```

I want to have this table:

```
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------+
|num|Commentdate        |comment           |distance_min|
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------+
|1  |2017-03-12 03:19:50|super film        |null        |
|2  |2017-03-12 03:19:58|très bon film     |8           |
|3  |2017-03-12 03:21:50|tres mauvais      |null        |
|4  |2017-03-12 03:21:51|incroyable ce film|16          |
|5  |2017-03-12 03:21:58|incroyable ce film|0           |
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------+
```

- For the first comment there is nothing in the past 10 minutes --> he
  get Null
- For the second comment there is only one comment and the distance is 8
- For the third comment there is nothing in the past 10 minutes --> he
  get Null
- For the fourth comment there is only one comment and the distance is 16
- For the fifth comment there is 2 comments in the past 10 minutes and the distance are {0 and 16} so the min distance is 0

For information I use this computation of distance:

```
// Distance de Levenshtein
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def levenshtein(s1: String, s2: String): Int = {
  val memorizedCosts = mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Int]()

  def lev: ((Int, Int)) => Int = {
    case (k1, k2) =>
      memorizedCosts.getOrElseUpdate((k1, k2), (k1, k2) match {
        case (i, 0) => i
        case (0, j) => j
        case (i, j) =>
          ParSeq(1 + lev((i - 1, j)),
            1 + lev((i, j - 1)),
            lev((i - 1, j - 1))
              + (if (s1(i - 1) != s2(j - 1)) 1 else 0)).min
      })
  }

  lev((s1.length, s2.length))
}

levenshtein("a B c", "a b c")
```

I try to look at window functions but all I can do is agregate function. How to apply a window function (here the computation of a distance betwen 2 speech)) to each line and do agregation (get the min) only at the end?

If it is not possible. does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution:

Step1: Use "collect_list" to get all the comment that are in the time window.

Step2: Use a user define function to compare a comment to a list of comment

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Step0:

Définition of commentaire:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
var commentaires = sc.parallelize(Array((1, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:05:50"), "super film"), (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:19:58"), "très bon film"),(3, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 04:21:50"), "tres mauvais"), (4, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:21:51"), "incroyable ce film"), (5, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:21:58"), "incroyable ce film"), (6, Timestamp.valueOf("2017-03-12 03:22:58"), "incroyable ce film"))).toDF("num", "dateCommentaire", "commentaire")
```

Step1: Use collect_list

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,concat_ws, collect_list}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
var w1 = Window.orderBy(col("dateCommentaire").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-10*60,-1)
commentaires = commentaires.withColumn("listePreviousCom", collect_list("commentaire") over(w1))
```

Step2: Compute minDistance:

```
var getMinDistance: ((String, mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => (Option[Double]))= (comment: String, listComment: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
    // initialisation de la liste (with "-1.0" to have a list of Double)
    var listDistance = List(-1.0)
    listDistance = listDistance.filter(_ != -1.0) // Delete "-1.0"
    for ((commentaire, indexe) <- listComment.zipWithIndex) {
        listDistance = lev(commentaire, comment) :: listDistance
    }
    listDistance = listDistance.reverse
    if (listDistance.size >= 1){
        var minDistance = listDistance.min
        Some(minDistance)
    }
     else {
         None
    }
}

val getMinDistance_f= udf(getMinDistance)

commentaires = commentaires.withColumn("minDistance", getMinDistance_f($"commentaire", $"listePreviousCom"))
```